# rosjava.jar missing certain packages

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got rosjava.jar from delbian packages, in the dist folder. But when I use this as a reference lib in eclipse, I realise certain packages like org.ros.node and org.ros.android are missing.

Can someone please explain how I could solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11218/rosjava.jar-missing-certain-packages/) by [sskk89](https://answers.ros.org/users/1070/sskk89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

org.ros.android comes from the rosjava.android packages (http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout?repo=android).  The other missing jars are most likely built when you build the rosjava package.  The manifest.xml file of a package specifies dependencies and when you run "rosmake" on the package it will generate the jar files for each of those dependencies.

I recommend installing rosjava and rosjava.android from source.  Here's (hopefully) a helpful guide:

1. Install ROS electric, unstable, or later

   ```
   a.  ‘sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full’ (for electric)
   ```
2. Clone the latest rosjava source from googlecode into a directory in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

   ```
   Install Mercurial (hg) : ‘sudo apt-get install hg’

   Go to http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout and Follow “Command-line access” instructions
   ```
3. Run ‘rospack profile’ to update your environment
4. Build rosjava

   ```
   ‘rosmake rosjava’
   ```

**Continue for Andorid setup**

1. Install eclipse

   ```
   ‘sudo apt-get install eclipse’
   ```
2. Install the Andorid SDK

   ```
   Follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
   ```
3. Clone the latest rosjava.android source from googlecode into a directory in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

   ```
   Go to http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout?repo=android and Follow “Command-line access” instructions
   ```
4. Run ‘rospack profile’ to update your environment
5. Build rosjava.android

   ```
   ‘rosmake rosjava.android’
   ```

From here you should have a working environment.  To run the tutorials, run "rosmake" on the one you want, then import it into eclipse.  If you're doing Android dev you may need to import android_gingerbread or android_honeycomb_mr2 into eclipse also, and add them as project references.

android_gingerbread and android_honeycomb_mr2 are the packages (eclipse projects) that provide org.ros.rosjava.android.

To create a new rosjava package you can follow the instructions here : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build

The only difference for android is that the build.xml file should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <property file="ros.properties"/>
  <include file="${ros.pkg.rosjava_bootstrap.dir}/android.xml"/>
</project>
```

You'll also need to set up the right exports.  Add this to your manifest.xml file:

```
<export>
  <rosjava-android-lib target="android-9" />
  <rosjava-src location="src" />
  <rosjava-src location="gen" />
  <rosjava-src location="res" />
</export>
```

After running rosmake you should be able to import your the package into eclipse and begin development.

---

Originally posted by [johnfertitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/380/johnfertitta/) with karma: 89 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5